# Error al pasar datos tipo decimal

Tags: c#

Tengo problemas al pasar registros tipo decimal a sql desde c#. Pasa bien los campos tipo `int`, `date`, `bit`, pero los decimales los pasa en 0 (0.00).

Este es parte del código de transferencia:

```
while (ReaderMov.Read())
{   
    command.Parameters.Clear();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asie", ReaderMov[0].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fech", ReaderMov[1].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", ReaderMov[2].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conc", ReaderMov[3].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuen", ReaderMov[4].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", ReaderMov[5].ToString());

    decimal NumDeb = Convert.ToDecimal("@debi");
    decimal.TryParse("@debi", out NumDeb);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@debi", NumDeb.ToString());

    decimal NumCre = Convert.ToDecimal("@cred");
    decimal.TryParse("@cred", out NumCre);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cred", NumCre.ToString());

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nroc", ReaderMov[8].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deta", ReaderMov[9].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoja", ReaderMov[10].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reng", ReaderMov[11].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vari", ReaderMov[12].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pase", ReaderMov[13].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptov", ReaderMov[14].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", ReaderMov[15].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fein", ReaderMov[16].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fefi", ReaderMov[17].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fevt", ReaderMov[18].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usua", ReaderMov[19].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maqu", ReaderMov[20].ToString());

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, bienvenido a [es.so], ¿tu código te genera algún error? ¿Qué tipo de dato tienes en la base de datos? Recomiendo que revises [ask] para que tu pregunta pueda tener mayor atención ;)

Comment: Pasa los datos tipo decimal en 0 (0.00) y no con el valor real

Comment: Aca hay otro problema.. donde estas agarrando los datos 6 y 7??? supongo que esos seran los numeros que queres pasar a decimal, pero no los estas tomando de ningun lado.

Comment: @JorgeCampos si no tienes problemas con el `ToDecimal`, ¿Porqué usas de manera incorrecta el `decimal.TryParse("@debi", out NumDeb);`? Al utilizar `TryParse` estás convirtiendo la cadena `@debi` a un `Decimal`, y al no poder convertirla a tu variable `NumDeb` le está asignando el valor por defecto cero.

Answer (score 1):

El formato con el que envías la información no es el correcto. Por ejemplo, la sentencia  `decimal NumDeb = Convert.ToDecimal("@debi");` intentará convertir `@debi` a decimal, lo cual te ocasionará un error.

Si lo que intentas en enviar el valor del `reader` cambia los parámetros decimales por lo siguiente:

```
decimal NumDeb = Convert.ToDecimal(ReaderMov[6].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@debi", NumDeb.ToString());

decimal NumCre = Convert.ToDecimal(ReaderMov[7].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cred", NumCre.ToString());
```

Comment: me parece que entendiste mal, y le llegan 0.00 en lugar del numero que quiere mandar...

Comment: correcto, llega 0.00 en lugar de 1856.23 por ejemplo

Comment: Hola puedes explicar esto? decimal.TryParse("@debi", out NumDeb); ese código siempre produce 0 en NumDeb. Debería pasar como cadena una número que se pueda convertir a decimal no un literal. Saludos

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra, cuando al usar `decimal.TryParse` no puede convertir una cadena a un decimal entonces a la variable de salida le asigna el valor cero. Revisa: [Decimal.TryParse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,5c1db31dc24c737e) y [Number.TryParseDecimal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,59ee76ca52a3da02)

Comment: Hola. Eso es lo que he dicho. Ese código hace que en la variable NumDeb se rellene un 0. Saludos

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra no comprendo de qué forma se envía un cero. Lo que hace es validar que el contenido de la variable sea un `decimal`, y si por alguna razón no se pudiera parsear el valor, entonces sí se envía un cero. Mientras la posición del `reader` tenga un valor válido no se enviaría ningún cero.

Comment: Veamos el código. decimal NumDeb = Convert.ToDecimal(ReaderMov[6].ToString()); // aquí NumDeb se establece con el valor del campo del reader.
decimal.TryParse("@debi", out NumDeb); // se "parsea" una cadena y al no ser convertible a decimal, se "machaca"  NumDeb con 0.
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@debi", NumDeb); /// se envía NumDeb = 0

Comment: Para mi que sobran los TryParse() al menos. O haría esto personalmente. decimal.TryParse(ReaderMov[6].ToString(), out NumDeb);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@debi", NumDeb.ToString());

Comment: También estaría bien saber qué tipo es el parámetro @debi ya que por lo visto se está enviando una cadena (un decimal convertido en cadena)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra tienes razón acerca de que está demás intentar parsear. He editado la respuesta. Saludos ;)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra debi y cred son los parámetros que almacenan datos decimales

Comment: Hola, si son parámetros de tipo decimal en tu consulta o procedimiento almacenado, no te hace falta el hacer .ToString(). El método AddWithValues()  tiene como entrada el nombre del parámetro y un object con el valor. Pasa directamente NumDeb. Saludos.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra efectivamente saque el .ToString() y funciono. Gracias por tu ayuda.Abrazo